# How to filter array of objects by values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, i'm having the filtered ids in one array and having the all data's in another array of objects. I want to display filtered ids values mentioned in array of value.

```
var allData = [
    {
      id:'10',
      name:'jhon'
    },
    {
      id:'11',
      name:'lewis'
    },
    {
      id:'12',
      name:'taylor'
    },
    {
      id:'13',
      name:'adam'
    },
    {
      id:'14',
      name:'bolive'
    }
];

var addedIds = ['10', '12', '14'];
```

My javascript code,

```
allData.filter(data, function (item) {
    item.map(function(list, i) {
        if (list.id.indexOf(addedIds[i]) === -1) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(list);
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you think this `addedIds[i]` does, and why do you think `i` is a relevant index in this context?

Comment: To clarify you want to output the name of each id listed on `addedIds` ?

Comment: my result should be like this, [{id:"10",name:'jhon' }, {id:"12",name:'taylor' }, {id:"14",name:'bolive' }]

Comment: your filter callback function should `return true` when a given record should be in the resulting array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var allData = [
    {
      id:'10',
      name:'jhon'
    },
    {
      id:'11',
      name:'lewis'
    },
    {
      id:'12',
      name:'taylor'
    },
    {
      id:'13',
      name:'adam'
    },
    {
      id:'14',
      name:'bolive'
    }
];

var addedIds = ['10', '12', '14'];

var allData = allData.filter(function (item) {   
    if (addedIds.indexOf(item.id) !== -1) return item;
});

console.log(allData);
```

Comment: Also how i can achieve filter search by keys? The search can be filter by key id or key name.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. In this case, only indexOf require array, not array of objects.

Comment: Is this correct? var allData = allData.filter(function (item) {   
    if ($('input').val().indexOf(item.id) !== -1 || $('input').val().indexOf(item. name) !== -1) return item;
});

Comment: I think this do not works, because `$('input').val()` can returns objects and not array. But, I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

`Array.prototype.filter` only expects one parameter: a function that is passed every item in the array and returns true or false depending on if that item should be included in the filter or not.

You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf` to see if a string is in an array.

```js
var allData = [{
  id: '10',
  name: 'jhon'
}, {
  id: '11',
  name: 'lewis'
}, {
  id: '12',
  name: 'taylor'
}, {
  id: '13',
  name: 'adam'
}, {
  id: '14',
  name: 'bolive'
}];

var addedIds = ['10', '12', '14'];

var filteredData = allData.filter(function(item) {
  return addedIds.indexOf(item.id) != -1;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var allData = [{
  id: '10',
  name: 'jhon'
}, {
  id: '11',
  name: 'lewis'
}, {
  id: '12',
  name: 'taylor'
}, {
  id: '13',
  name: 'adam'
}, {
  id: '14',
  name: 'bolive'
}];

var addedIds = ['10', '12', '14'];
var addedIdsSet = new Set(addedIds);
var result = allData.filter(e => addedIdsSet.has(e.id));
console.log(result)
```

I personally like turning arrays of Ids into a Set, and moving from there:

```
var addedIdsSet = new Set(addedIds);
```

Then the rest is a matter of filtering (like you tried) using the set:

```
console.log(allData.filter(x => addedIdsSet.has(x.id)))
```

Note: Using a Set is only really *necessary* if you have a large list of Ids and want to squeeze out some performance, as this will drop complexity from O(n^2) to O(n), where **n** is the number of elements in allData. 
Regardless, I like using a Set anyway because the code ends up looking cleaner too!

Answer (score 1):

```
var allData = [
{
  id:'10',
  name:'jhon'
},
{
  id:'11',
  name:'lewis'
},
{
  id:'12',
  name:'taylor'
},
{
  id:'13',
  name:'adam'
},
{
  id:'14',
  name:'bolive'
}
];

var addedIds = ['10', '12', '14'];

var filteredValues = allData.filter(x => addedIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1);
console.log(filteredValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var allData = [
    {
      id:'10',
      name:'jhon'
    },
    {
      id:'11',
      name:'lewis'
    },
    {
      id:'12',
      name:'taylor'
    },
    {
      id:'13',
      name:'adam'
    },
    {
      id:'14',
      name:'bolive'
    }
];

var addedIds = ['10', '12', '14'];

var filtered_results = [];

allData.filter(function (item) {
  for(var k in addedIds){
      if(item.id === addedIds[k]){
          filtered_results.push(item);
      }
  }
});
console.log(filtered_results);
```